# How to modify jar name generate by cmd sbt package

Tags: scala, sbt

For example , if I ran `sbt package` and sbt will generate a jar name like `project_2.11-version.jar`, how can I modify this name to a random name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what the [docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Artifacts.html) say:

> The generated artifact name is determined by the artifactName setting.
>   This setting is of type (ScalaVersion, ModuleID, Artifact) => String.

And the default implementation is:

```
artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  artifact.name + "-" + module.revision + "." + artifact.extension
}
```

You can copy this code into your `build.sbt` or `Build.scala` file and change how it constructs the artefact name. For example:

```
artifactName := { (sv: ScalaVersion, module: ModuleID, artifact: Artifact) =>
  java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString + "." + artifact.extension
}
```

Comment: It works for me. How are you testing? What's not working? Restart or reload your SBT first. Then do `clean` followed by `package`. Observe it print something like: `[info] Packaging .../target/scala-2.12/9615e7a1-41f0-40ab-abc0-ca254a0da169.jar ...`

Comment: oh, I see the jar name is change from `project-1.1.jar` to `project-simple.jar`， but sbt will still publish `project-1.1.jar` and since there is no such jar,sbt will give an error.How to change `publish` settings?

Comment: @JeremyLen I'm not sure what is your use case, but it sounds a bit strange that you want to change reliable packaging and publishing naming scheme to something else. By default your project name `name` and Scala versions are used to reliably identify the artefact. You can try to play with publishing settings in a similar way: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html but maybe you should just change your project name?